Trouble showing a legend in levelplot
I have this data on different countries in R:
library(lattice)
library(viridisLite)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

generate_all_data <- function(countries, n = 50) {
  all_data <- data.frame()
  
  current_date <- Sys.Date()
  date_range <- seq(current_date - years(5), current_date, by = "day")
  
  for (country in countries) {
    country_data <- data.frame(
      country = country,
      var1 = rnorm(n^2, mean = 5, sd = 2),
      var2 = rnorm(n^2, mean = 5, sd = 2),
      date = sample(date_range, n^2, replace = TRUE)
    )
    country_data$days_passed <- as.numeric(current_date - country_data$date)
    
    all_data <- rbind(all_data, country_data)
  }
  
  return(all_data)
}

countries <- c("USA", "China", "Germany", "Brazil", "India", "Japan")
all_country_data <- generate_all_data(countries)

I made these heatmaps of all the different countries:
coul <- magma(100, direction = -1)

create_country_plot <- function(data, country) {
  country_data <- data %>% filter(country == !!country)
  days_passed_matrix <- matrix(country_data$days_passed, nrow = sqrt(nrow(country_data)))
  
  levelplot(days_passed_matrix, 
            col.regions = coul,
            xlab = "Variable 1",
            ylab = "Variable 2",
            main = country,
            scales = list(x = list(at = seq(1, sqrt(nrow(country_data)), length.out = 3), 
                                   labels = round(seq(min(country_data$var1), max(country_data$var1), length.out = 3), 1)),
                          y = list(at = seq(1, sqrt(nrow(country_data)), length.out = 3), 
                                   labels = round(seq(min(country_data$var2), max(country_data$var2), length.out = 3), 1))),
            colorkey = FALSE)  # Remove individual colorkeys
}

plots <- lapply(countries, function(country) create_country_plot(all_country_data, country))

max_days <- max(all_country_data$days_passed)
legend_grob <- levelplot(matrix(1:max_days, nrow=1), 
                         col.regions = coul,
                         colorkey = list(space = "bottom", 
                                         height = 0.8,
                                         width = 0.8,
                                         at = seq(0, max_days, length.out = 6),
                                         labels = list(at = seq(0, max_days, length.out = 6),
                                                       labels = paste0(round(seq(0, max_days, length.out = 6)), " days"))),
                         scales = list(draw = FALSE),
                         xlab = "", ylab = "")$legend$right

plot_grid <- arrangeGrob(
  grobs = plots,
  ncol = 3
)

combined_plot <- grid.arrange(
  plot_grid,
  legend_grob,
  ncol = 1,
  heights = c(10, 1),
  top = textGrob("Relationship Between Variables Over Time Across Countries", 
                 gp = gpar(fontsize = 16, font = 2))
)

print(combined_plot)

When I try to run this code, I am able to see the plots:

But I get this error:
Error in vapply(x$grobs, as.character, character(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 0

How can I fix the legend in the above plot?
I am trying to have a single legend appear in the above diagram that looks like the legend below:


Note - here is the code for the above plot with the desired legend:
library(lattice)
library(viridisLite)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

n <- 100  
end_date <- Sys.Date()  
start_date <- end_date - years(4) 
dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, length.out = n)

var1 <- seq(90, 100, length.out = n)
var2 <- seq(0, 5, length.out = n)
grid <- expand.grid(var1 = var1, var2 = var2)


grid$date <- rep(dates, each = n)

grid$days_since_today <- as.numeric(end_date - grid$date)

days_since_today_matrix <- matrix(grid$days_since_today, nrow = n, ncol = n)

coul <- magma(100, direction = -1) 

p <- levelplot(days_since_today_matrix, 
               col.regions = coul,
               xlab = "var1",
               ylab = "var2",
               main = "var2 vs var1 Over Time",
               scales = list(x = list(at = seq(1, n, length.out = 6), 
                                      labels = round(seq(min(var1), max(var1), length.out = 6), 1)),
                             y = list(at = seq(1, n, length.out = 6), 
                                      labels = round(seq(min(var2), max(var2), length.out = 6), 1))),
               colorkey = list(at = seq(0, max(grid$days_since_today), length.out = 5),
                               labels = list(at = seq(0, max(grid$days_since_today), length.out = 5),
                                             labels = paste(round(seq(0, max(grid$days_since_today), length.out = 5)), "days"))))


Not exactly what I wanted, but something similar:
library(lattice)
library(viridisLite)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

generate_all_data <- function(countries, n = 50) {
  all_data <- data.frame()
  
  current_date <- Sys.Date()
  date_range <- seq(current_date - years(5), current_date, by = "day")
  
  for (country in countries) {
    country_data <- data.frame(
      country = country,
      var1 = rnorm(n^2, mean = 5, sd = 2),
      var2 = rnorm(n^2, mean = 5, sd = 2),
      date = sample(date_range, n^2, replace = TRUE)
    )
    country_data$days_passed <- as.numeric(current_date - country_data$date)
    
    all_data <- rbind(all_data, country_data)
  }
  
  return(all_data)
}

countries <- c("USA", "China", "Germany", "Brazil", "India", "Japan")
all_country_data <- generate_all_data(countries)

coul <- magma(100, direction = -1)

create_country_plot_with_legend <- function(data, country) {
  country_data <- data %>% filter(country == !!country)
  days_passed_matrix <- matrix(country_data$days_passed, nrow = sqrt(nrow(country_data)))
  
  levelplot(days_passed_matrix, 
            col.regions = coul,
            xlab = "Variable 1",
            ylab = "Variable 2",
            main = country,
            scales = list(x = list(at = seq(1, sqrt(nrow(country_data)), length.out = 3), 
                                   labels = round(seq(min(country_data$var1), max(country_data$var1), length.out = 3), 1)),
                          y = list(at = seq(1, sqrt(nrow(country_data)), length.out = 3), 
                                   labels = round(seq(min(country_data$var2), max(country_data$var2), length.out = 3), 1))),
            colorkey = list(space = "right",   
                            at = seq(0, max(country_data$days_passed), length.out = 6),
                            labels = list(at = seq(0, max(country_data$days_passed), length.out = 6),
                                          labels = paste0(round(seq(0, max(country_data$days_passed), length.out = 6)), " days")))
            )
}

plots_with_legends <- lapply(countries, function(country) create_country_plot_with_legend(all_country_data, country))

plot_grid_with_legends <- arrangeGrob(
  grobs = plots_with_legends,
  ncol = 3
)

combined_plot_with_legends <- grid.arrange(
  plot_grid_with_legends,
  top = textGrob("Relationship Between Variables Over Time Across Countries", 
                 gp = gpar(fontsize = 16, font = 2))
)

print(combined_plot_with_legends)


